# Не срабатывает триггер UnSelect у ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, wpf, анимация, триггер

Переопределил стиль ListBoxItem с целью изменить анимацию select\unselect.

```
 <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Selected">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <jt:GridLengthAnimation 
                Storyboard.TargetName="SelectColumn"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"                                                        
                To="0.1"
                Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>

<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Unselected">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
            <jt:GridLengthAnimation 
            Storyboard.TargetName="SelectColumn"
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"                                                        
            To="0"
            Duration="0:0:0.4"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Триггер Selected срабатывает как надо, но вот UnSelected не работает и итем остаётся выделенным. В чем может быть проблема? (SelectColumn это столбец Grid)

Comment: Почему не сделать это обычным триггером (Trigger) на свойство `IsSelected`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP делал и так, результат такой же, работает только в 1 сторону